# iOS SDK: Corner Radius shows incorrectly

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

Here I've got screen designed in Sketch:

[image]

There are two buttons. Now I am designing such button in Xcode and I am setting UIButton's corner radius this way:

```
layer.cornerRadius = 30
clipsToBounds = true
```

But as the result I am having something strange:

[image]

You can see some corner in the center if the left and right sides of button. What can I do?

Comment: use `layer.cornerRadius = yourbuttonwidth/2`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : it must be `layer.cornerRadius = yourbuttonheight/2`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To generate round corners on such a button, if you set the `cornerRadius` value to `30`, you are assuming that the height of the button is set to `60`.

This may not be true on all the devices, depending on how you handle your layout. Seeing your image, it looks like the button is slightly less high than what you designed.

Two options :

1. Use Auto-Layout and add a constraint of "fixed height" on your button, with a value of `60`, so your button always has a height of 60 points.
2. Implement a `UIButton` subclass, and in the `layoutSubviews` method, set the `cornerRadius` to half the height of the `bounds` of your button. This way, any time the system re-draws the button, the corner radius will be updated appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Make a custom `UIButton` Class and set all of your desired buttons to that class so you don't need to put any more code in every `UIViewController` class.

The custom `UIButton` class should look like this:

```
import UIKit

class RoundCornerButton: UIButton {

   override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
       // Drawing code
       self.clipsToBounds = true
       self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width / 2
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your button's layer has a different size now, than in Sketch.
After `layoutSubviews` set the corner radius to be the half of the layers height.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
  super.layoutSubviews()
  layer.cornerRadius = layer.bounds.height / 2.0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing code in every controller if you are going to use multiple times, You can make extension for making circular buttons, views as well using below code.In which you can pass cornerRadius, borderWidth and UIColor.

```
import UIKit

extension UIView
{
    func makeCircular(cornerRadius: CGFloat, borderWidth: CGFloat, borderColor: UIColor)
    {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius * self.bounds.size.width
        self.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor as CGColorRef
        self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

you can simply pass the values as per your requirement.

Usage :

```
    snapButton.makeCircular(0.5, borderWidth: 1.0, borderColor: UIColor.clearColor())
```